# Python: Regex sub with only number and one dot (.) if have

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to use `regex.sub` to replace any string to string have number and only one dot (.) if have.

Example:

```
string = "aa122..2a" # "122.2"
```

```
string = "aa122a3a" # "1223"
```

I tried

```
re.sub(r'[^\d\.{0,1}]', '', string)
```

But `{0,1}` not work.

Comment: What about if there are two non-consecutive dots, such as `aa122.3.4.5a`?

Comment: it will accept only one first dot found, like "122.345"

Answer (score 2):

You want to delete all non-digits and all dots except first one, so the regex should be

```
import regex

regex.sub(r"([^\d.]|(?<=\..*)\.)", "", string)
```

The first part matches any character that is not a digit or the dot. The second part matches any dot that has another dot before it, so only the first dot is preserved.

Because of the use of variable-length lookbehinds, the stock `re` module doesn't work. You need [`regex` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) for this feature.

Test:

```
>>> regex.sub(r"([^\d.]|(?<=\..*)\.)", "", "aa122.3.4.5a")
'122.345'
```

Comment: i tried, but if string = "aa122..2zz..." it convert to '122.2.'. My expected is "122.2"

Comment: Then I recommend [the `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), stock `re` isn't up to this task.

Comment: ty, i only upvote because main question is re. And maybe its cant in this case

Comment: If you only use lookbehind, you can cheese it by flipping the string and transforming the regexp to use lookahead instead, which is not limited to constant length: `re.sub(r"([^\d.]|\.(?=.*\.))", "", string[::-1])[::-1]` works (with standard `re`).